# Eigen decomposition of a matrix of form W * diag(S) * W' for matrix exponential in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, svd, eigenvalue, eigenvector

`W` is a tall and skinny real valued matrix, and `diag(S)` is a diagonal matrix consists of `+1` or `-1` on the diagonal. I want the eigen decomposition of `A = W * diag(S) * W'` where single quote denotes transposition. The main problem is that `A` is pretty big. Since `A` is symmetric, rank deficient, and I actually know the maximum rank of `A` (from `W`), I think I should be able to do this efficiently. Any idea how to approach this?

My eventual goal is to compute the matrix exponential of `A` without using MATLAB's `expm` which is pretty slow for big matrices and does not take advantage of rank deficiency. If `A = U * diag(Z) * U'` is the eigen decomposition, `exp(A) = U * diag(exp(Z)) * U'`.

While finding an orthogonal `U` such that `W * diag(S) * W' = U' * diag(Z) * U'` looks promising to have an easy algorithm, I need some linear algebra help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd first perform the so called 'thin' QR factorization of W, then compute the eigenvalue decomposition of `R*diag(S)*R'`, then use this to compute the eig decomposition of A.

```
N = 10;
n=3;
S = 2*(rand(1,n)>0.5)-1;
W = rand(N,n);

[Q,R] = qr(W,0);
[V,D] = eig(R*diag(S)*R');

%this is the non rank-deficient part of eig(W*diag(S)*W')
D_A = D;
V_A = Q*V;

%compare with
[V_full,D_full] = eig(W*diag(S)*W');
```

Hope this helps.

A.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB actually has an implementation for retrieving the largest (or smallest) eigen values and vectors. Use `eigs(A,k)` to get the `k` largest.

To get the largest only, one can use the [Power iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) method, or better yet Rayleigh quotient iteration.